# Tossing a coin k times

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

We toss a fair coin $k$ times and we set the following possible results:

$A$: both heads and tails appear at least 1 time.
$B$: tails appears at least one time.

For which values of $k$ are $A$ and $B$ independent ?

Now i know that the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is $B$ itself and I want to use the Bayes rule but I cant figure out the probability of $A$.

So how to find $A$???

Comment: was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

If $A \cap B = A$ then to show independence you would have to show
$P[A] = P[A \cap B] = P[A]P[B]$, which implies that $P[A] = 1,0$. When, if ever, does this happen?

By the way, to compute $A$, let $X$ be the number of heads in $k$ flips. This has a binomial distribution with probability $p=1/2$. The set $A$ is the event 
$$
  A
= \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}\{ X = i\}
$$
(if you have at least one head, but not $k$, there will also be at least one tail). You can compute $P[A]$ then as
$$
  P[A]
= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{k}{i} p^i(1-p)^{k-i}
= \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \binom{k}{i}
$$